# Getting No Data received error when trying to go to App on Heroku

Tags: facebook, heroku

I am trying to make a website using the Facebook API. This is my first time doing something like this. I followed the directions on FB for setting it up on Heroku, but when I attempt to go to the URL that was just created I get the error No data received.

Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I do not know what the issue is. I am following instructions online and it should ask for fb permissions and then log into Heroku.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error occurred because the internet was to slow and it kept timing out even though other pages seemed to be working fine.